# Why no error for the code as else is un-indented?

Tags: python

WHy doesn't this code gives an error in python as the else part is un-indented and doesn't have a starting if block.

```
guess=7
c=1
for c in range(1,6):
  g = int(input("guess a number from 1 to 20:"))
  if (g==guess):
    print("you win")
    break 
else:
  print("you lose")
```

Answer (score 0):

That else is for the `for` loop. If the for loop is completed without a break, it is not implemented, if not the `else` block will be executed.

```
guess=7
c=1
for c in range(1,6):
  g = int(input("guess a number from 1 to 20:"))
  if (g==guess):
    print("you win")
    break 
else:  # This else is for "for loop"
  print("you lose")
```